# Drawing a white line on an image using (rho, theta)

Tags: matlab

I want to draw a line on the following image using ( rho , theta ) of the detected line using the Hough transformation.

[image]
.

expected output

[image]

.

It's not being able to display the line, as `y` values are negative.

```
input_image = gray_imread('Scratch1.1.png');
maxPeaks = 1; 
fillgap = 500; 
minline = 7; 
binary_image = edge(input_image,'canny');
[H,T,R] = hough(binary_image);
threshPeaks = ceil(0.3*max(H(:)));    
P  = houghpeaks(H, maxPeaks, 'threshold', threshPeaks);    
hlines = houghlines(binary_image, T, R, P, 'FillGap', fillgap, 'MinLength', minline);

h_line = hlines(1);

rho = h_line.rho;
theta = h_line.theta;

imshow(input_image);
hold on;
x = h_line.point1(1):h_line.point2(1);
y = (rho - x* cos(theta) )/ sin(theta);
plot(x,y);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you inspected the values of x and y to see if they seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not need to create the y variable from the rho/theta values.

Instead, you can use the `h_line.point1(2)` value using the below code.

```
x = linspace(h_line.point1(1),h_line.point2(1),512);
y = linspace(h_line.point1(2),h_line.point2(2),512);
```

Which gives you the output
[image: Desired Output]

Also, if you look at your original equation
    y = (rho - x* cos(theta) )/ sin(theta);

The outputs of the hough function are in degrees not radians which MATLAB's sin functions use. If you wish to use those, you will have to use `sind` and `cosd`

```
y = (rho - x* cosd(theta) )/ sind(theta);
```